# why is this if,elif and if statement not working with raw_input

Tags: python-2.7

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
quest = raw_input("What quest do you chose?, 1 for slaying a dragon, 2 for defeating the evil wizard and 3 for killing the kraken ")
if quest == 1
  quest == "so you want to slay a dragon."
   elif quest == 2
    quest == "do you have something against wizards, relax im joking"
     elif quest = 3
      quest == "have you got a boat, better jet a submarine?"
      else quest = "so you have no quest, hm... in that case GET OUT OF MY SWAMP"

print quest
```

it keeps giving me  this error:

File "python", line 3
    if quest == 1
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The elifs and the else should not be indented (only indent the code inside them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "==" is a logical operator you can't assign a value to quest using it.
2. after putting the if elif condition you should put ":"
3. indenting in python is crucial and essential.
4. print is a method you need parenthesis to print quest
5. check the code snippet below it is a working version of your code

---

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
quest = raw_input("What quest do you chose?, 1 for slaying a dragon, 2 for defeating 
the evil wizard and 3 for killing the kraken\n")

if quest == "1":
   quest = "so you want to slay a dragon."
elif quest == "2":
   quest = "do you have something against wizards, relax im joking"
elif quest == "3":
   quest = "have you got a boat, better jet a submarine?"
else:
   quest = "so you have no quest, hm... in that case GET OUT OF MY SWAMP"

print(quest)
```